# How do I get individual userId, id, title and posts from jsonplaceholder.typecode.com

Tags: python

I need help with an assignment regarding API calls. Here are the following parameters:

1. use python to get on Api (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)

   ```
   import requests, json
   url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
   r = requests.get(url)
   data = json.loads(r.text)
   ```
2. capture list of dictionaries from one endpoint and reverse sort

   ```
   for item in reversed(data):
      print(item)
   ```
3. Print a post for specific userId

   ```
   print(data[0])
   ```
4. Print a post from specific userId that only prints out the title, id, or post

   When I try:

   ```
   print(data[0].id[1])
   ```

I get a 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'. Any help is appreciated. I just need help with question 4.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp print(data[0]) prints out the first userId in the dict and its content. Your guess gives me an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access dictionary element in python you use `dictionary['<key>']` (not `dictionary.<key>`). Try:

```
print(data[0]['id'])
print(data[0]['userId'])
```

Comment: how would you print out the following? where userId = 1, and id=5 ?

Comment: You'd need to go over data (like you did in your 2. point) and check if the ids match (`if item['iuserId'] == 1 and item['id'] == 5: print(item['title'])`)

Comment: Thank you sir. I learned so much today.